# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_i386_GPFLT) when migrating existing tests to XCTest

Tags: core-data, xctest

I have been using GHUnit with it without any problem to test a library.

This library basically perform calls to an API and use CoreData to decrease the number of API calls.

Then, I decided to switch to XCTest:

1. Created the test Target
2. Created the test class
3. Tests runs fine! wheeee!!!

However anything I try to do that involves CoreData I get a error: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_i386_GPFLT)`

It does not happens with GHUnit, it is the same code!
Also, it runs if I set the "Host Application".

I know that the error is related to trying to access an address that the code is not suppose to, but there's no more details.

I see that in the DatabaseManager the line:

```
NSString *modelPath = [bundle pathForResource:bundlePath ofType:@"momd"];
```

Returns nil, but, as I said **it runs fine when using GHUnit 
or simply using the library.**

I feel like I am missing some property in the project settings.

I have added the log here:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wilsolutions/96e3ae1310ccae86d344/raw/03ea1dfcdab75fc215baaba9d07123bd2e915617/gistfile1.txt

tkx